# THREE.js disposing gltf objects

Tags: javascript, three.js, dispose, gltf

I have a THREE.js project that includes an imported gltf object:

```
loader.load("myObj.gltf",
function(gltf){
scene.add(gltf.scene);
},
undefined,
function(error){alert(error);});
```

Later, I clone the object:

```
let newObj = oldObj.clone();
```

In order to clear up memory, I have to dispose of the new cloned object, but not the original. How would I go about doing this? I tried dispose(), but that did not work.

Answer (score 2):

If you clone 3D objects like meshes, lines or point clouds in `three.js`, their materials, textures and geometries are not cloned but shared. So it should be sufficient to just remove cloned objects from the scene.

You can read more about what type of entities have a `dispose()` method in the following guide: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/How-to-dispose-of-objects